# Replace the last character of a parameter in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, replace

I have a stored procedure with this parameter

```
@START_TIME nvarchar(5)
```

I pass a value of `12:00` to this parameter.

And I want for replace the last character when insert data like this `12:01`

Here is a small reduction of the stored procedure:

```
@STAR_TIME nvarchar(5)
AS
    INSERT INTO AUDITORIUM (START_TIME)
    VALUES (@START_TIME)
```

Comment: Why you don't use the `time` data type?

Comment: What is the logic behind this? What have you tried yourself?

Comment: Well using the wrong datatype this becomes a real pain to work with. You have to cast/convert this back and forth a bunch of times. Meh!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this.

```
declare @STAR_TIME nvarchar(5) = '12:00'

select cast(cast(dateadd(minute, 1, CAST(@Star_Time as datetime)) as time) as nvarchar(5))
```

Ugh!!!

Or if you can use a time datatype this a lot easier.

```
declare @STAR_TIME time = '12:00'
select @STAR_TIME = DATEADD(minute, 1, @Star_TIME)
```

Comment: +1 for using `TIME` as this is the most appropriate datatype here!

Comment: Aye! In fact it is really the ONLY appropriate datatype here imho.